# which store should i install my cert

Tags: certificate, scheduled-tasks, x509certificate, x509certificate2

I have a service which need to read a cert to get authorized to query a web. The service is scheduled by windows task scheduler in non-interactive mode("Run whether the user is logged on or not".
In this case, where should i install the cert?

Answer (score 0):

For user certificate you need to install that cert under personal store

Comment: as i mentioned, it will run without the user logged on, so it can't be personal store. may be a public store but i'm not sure whether there is such store without user logged on